# Detecting when a task has finished through REST APIs

Tags: rest, nexus

The Nexus repository server by Sonatype offers a classical REST API. When an operation is triggered through the REST API, the call returns immediately, indicating through its status code whether or not the operation was *started* successfully. I am looking for a way to detect whether and when a job *finished* successfully.

In my concrete case, I am starting a backup task that writes out configuration databases in a serialized format to disk:

```
curl -X POST "$mynexus/service/rest/v1/tasks/$task-id/run" -H "accept: application/json"
```

which returns a 204 "task was run" immediately.

However, minutes after that happens, a manual check indicates that the on-disk file created by that task is still growing. Of course, I could try watching the output of `lsof` until that task seems finished, but that would be highly impractical, require root access to the server and also break the REST design.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487339/sonatype-nexus-synchronous-rest-calls) here has not received an answer since 2016, so I'll ask in a more general way, in the hope that the answer will be more generally applicable:

How can a REST client detect that an operation has completely finished on the server side when talking to a Sonatype Nexus 3.x series server?

If there is no such way, would you consider that an issue with Nexus or would you recommend to create a custom workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nexus 3` has a get task API endpoint which will give you different info about a specific task, including its `currentState`

```
GET /service/v1/tasks/{id}
```

Example API response taken from the below linked documentation:

```json
{
  "id" : "0261aed9-9f29-447b-8794-f21693b1f9ac",
  "name" : "Hello World",
  "type" : "script",
  "message" : null,
  "currentState" : "WAITING",
  "lastRunResult" : null,
  "nextRun" : null,
  "lastRun" : null
}
```

Reference: [Nexus get task API endpoint documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/tasks-api#TasksAPI-GetTask)

Comment: Is there any REST API for creating a task scheduler in Nexus 3.x ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is a groovy API though if scripting is enabled (and there is a REST script API endpoint to create and run scripts). You can find an example script [here](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/main/files/groovy/create_task.groovy) (disclaimer: I'm the author).